# Would a Sun Blade be considered to be made of metal, for the purposes of the Heat Metal spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, weapons

As the title states, would a [Sun Blade](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Sun%20Blade#content) be considered to be an item made of metal? I'm trying to work out if the [Heat Metal](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Heat%20Metal#content) spell would be effective against it.

A regular long sword would almost certainly be considered a metal weapon, but a Sun Blade is just the hilt with a magical blade. Longsword hilts were made of wood, wire, and leather, according to [this HowStuffWorks article about sword-making](https://science.howstuffworks.com/sword-making1.htm).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The description of the weapon is mum on the materials of the hilt so I think the DM needs to make a call on whether or not the heat metal spell has any effect.

One point to remember here: we're dealing with a game of magical fantasy. So while real world proxies can help inform the imagination, they shouldn't limit its scope.

Comment: Technically, even the weight is not specified for the *sun blade* in particular; "3 lbs." is not given as the weight of the [*sun blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/sun-blade) specifically, but rather [longswords](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/longsword) in general.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that the hilt is made of metal, at least partly. This is based solely on the fact that almost all swords have a metal component to the hilt or tang, even if the hilt or tang is encased in leather or a decorative material. In other words, holding this thing would get very hot if the spell heat metal was cast upon it.

Comment: Technically, tang is a part of the blade that goes thorough the hilt and into the pommel.

Comment: @Molot so you're thinking the tang/handle/pommel/hilt wouldn't have any metal since the blade isn't metal? Not a bad argument I suppose! So if it was just a magical cylinder that shoots out a blade of light, it could be made of anything.

Comment: I'm thinking that *might* be the case. It is hard to know for sure. Not with the (lack of) data in the books.